# "Так(,) а что ты хочешь?"

Tags: запятые

Нужна ли запятая, хотелось бы знать?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Я полагаю, что в большинстве случаев запятая в этой фразе не требуется,** произношение без паузы: ***Так а что ты хочешь?***

**Это разговорная реплика**, обращенная к собеседнику по поводу его рассказа о какой-либо ситуации. В ней говорится, что все события вполне объяснимы и ожидаемы, то есть примерно следующее: ***Так а что ты хочешь? Этого следовало ожидать.***

Такой же примерно смысл имеет такая реплика: ***Ну а что ты хочешь? Этого следовало ожидать.***

Запятая ставится в другой ситуации: **ТАк, а что тЫ хочешь? Ну, а что тЫ хочешь?** Но это уже не риторический, а конкретный вопрос.

Похожие примеры:

–  **Так а что** отвечать?  – сказал Перец.   [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Улитка на склоне (1966-1968)]

― А Барбридж? ― **Так а что** ― Барбридж? Как все, так и Барбридж… [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Пикник на обочине (1971)]

**Так а что** глядеть, пускай сидит, ― отговорился Михаил. ― Сильно-то надоедать ей не надо. [Валентин Распутин. Последний срок (1970)]

2. **С другой стороны, в Нацкорпусе есть примеры, когда запятая ставится, но при этом мне она кажется необоснованной,** например:

― Ну и что, что семьдесят: я за ним ухаживать буду… ― **Так, а что там ухаживать-то:** утром отнёс его в садик, посадил в креслице...  [Василий Шукшин. Печки-лавочки (1970-1972)]